# Connection between WebServices (JAVA - Jersey) With PHP client

Tags: java, php, web-services, jersey

i'm trying to connect a php client with a Java WS, i'm working on it but i can't find a good article talking about this, i have a little experience with PHP ws and PHP client, but not with Java, i looked on internet and stackoverflow too, but nothing helped me, someone have experience on Jersey(ws) - Php(client)?

Thanks.

Comment: Please ask a specific question about the technology in question.  Something this generic is likely to be closed.

Comment: Thanks, but i think in the title I specified the technologies (Connection between WebServices (JAVA - Jersey) With PHP client), I edited the post to improve the understanding of my problem.
Thanks for the reply Webnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution! thanks to stackoverfow and much other sites, and a partner, look this:

```
**curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8","Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"));**

**$postargs = array('user' => 'user', 'pass' => 'pass');**

**json_encode($postargs);**
```

This saved my life!!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter which implementation is used on the server side if you are implementing the client, as long as you are both using the same technology.

In your case, as you haven't said that, but speaking of Jersey, it's about RESTful webservices. Trying to say it in one sentence, with restful webservices you (not necessarily, but usually) request a resource via HTTP, let's say a book at Amazon's webservice by providing an URL to that resource.

So all you basically have to do is executing an HTTP GET operation to said resource and process the format of the answer (e.g. a JSON object).

I don't know what you searched for, but if you google for php and restful werbservice client, you'll certainly find more than you need.

Comment: Thanks Geziefer, i know i can use Curl() for this,but i need to make an authentication first, i never did that, how i should send the username and password and some parameters?

Comment: This would require some more detail on how the authentification mechanism is realized. If you consume an existing web service, it should mention its authentification requirements. But again, you'll find a lot of resources on the net by googling on that topic.

Comment: I'm at this poing, what do you think?
<?php
$r = curl_init();
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.mysite.com/authentication/login/");
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
//curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'charset=UTF-8'));
$d = array('username' => 'user', 'password' => 'password','param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2');
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d);
curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
//curl_setopt($r, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$data = curl_exec($r);
var_dump($data);

Comment: 1st) You shouldn't post a longer piece of code within a comment, it's unreadable, expand your question instead (preferrably with a update section, so that people still understand the original answers and comments). 2nd) Why not trying it out and giving us the results or pointing to a problem you have at a specific point?